# Network-shared hard drive cannot be connected to with Samba

Tags: linux, fedora, network-shares, samba

**Description:**

Hello. I am running Fedora 38 with samba software installed. I successfully setup a local network share of a home folder and it's been working fine for months now. Lately, I've wanted to setup a share of a folder in an external drive, and have not had any luck getting it to mount.

**Steps taken:**

I first followed [this Fedora guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/samba/), and recursively set the owner of the external drive's contents to the main host (and Samba) user. That didn't work. I then followed [this more detailed guide](https://fedoramagazine.org/fedora-32-simple-local-file-sharing-with-samba/) very closely, creating all the necessary users, checking the permissions, etc. It also doesn't work. When I try to mount my "documents" share on macOS, for instance, it tells me `The operation can't be completed because the original item for "media" can't be found.` Similarly, my other Fedora Workstation computer tells me, `No such file or directory`. Trying to login in CLI using `smbclient` just logs me out immediately with no error. Additionally, I've tried what these resources told me, without luck:

- [Ubuntu 18.10 samba share not working in non-home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103318/ubuntu-18-10-samba-share-not-working-in-non-home-folder)
- [How to set up an entire hard drive as a shared drive in Samba](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888205/how-to-set-up-an-entire-hard-drive-as-a-shared-drive-in-samba#893380)

**Technical information:**

My server's internal EXT4 hard drive is automatically mounted at `/mnt/hdd0`, with read/write access by user, and root. I am trying to share a folder at `/mnt/hdd0/Documents`.

This is my `/etc/smb.conf`:

```
[global]

[documents]
path = /mnt/hdd0/Documents
read only = no
```

Following [the second guide](https://fedoramagazine.org/fedora-32-simple-local-file-sharing-with-samba/), this should be all I need once I've assigned the correct permissions to my users and to Samba. However, I have tried it with these modifications, with no success:

```
[global]

[documents]
path = /mnt/hdd0/Documents
read only = no
readable = yes
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
available = yes
public = yes
valid users = samba_admin
force user = samba_admin
```

In any case, the share "documents" is publicly visible in both configurations, and the samba user "samba_admin" (wih rw permission) will show this error after the correct username and password are entered. Perhaps samba doesn't have read access to this folder somehow?